# Non blocking wait for condition evaluation in c#

Tags: c#, async-await, delay

I have a class which has a property called `ActiveDelay` which is used to define a duration during which a condition evaluation should wait before checking if the condition is still true after that time. The property `SetpointA` is the value used to compare the given value to.

Below is what I am currently doing

```
public void EvaluateCondition(T value)
{
    if(value.Equals(SetpointA))
    {
        Task.Delay(ActiveDelay).ContinueWith(_ => EvaluateConditionDelayed(GetValue())).Wait();
    }
}

private void EvaluateConditionDelayed(object value)
{
    if (value.Equals(SetpointA))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Waited and worked");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Condition now false");
    }
}
```

I am calling the function `EvaluateCondition` twice, once with a TimeSpan of 5 seconds and another time with a TimeSpan of 2 seconds and I expect that the 2 second call should finish before the 5 second call but what actually happens is that the 5 second call waits and then the 2 second call waits.

I assume there is somethings to do with async and await here but I haven't found information that helps me.

Something I want to make absolutely clear, **THESE DELAYS SHOULD NOT PAUSE THE PROGRAM**, they should only wait externally and allow the rest of the program to run unaffected.

**EXTENSIVE CODE SECTION**

Here is an extensive version of the above

```
public class AlarmCondition
{
    #region Property declaration
    public TimeSpan ActiveDelay { get; set; } // Need to be historised ?
    public TimeSpan ClearDelay { get; set; } // Need to be historised ?
    #endregion

    #region Constructor
    public AlarmCondition() { }

    public AlarmCondition(TimeSpan activeDelay, TimeSpan clearDelay)
    {
        ActiveDelay = activeDelay;
        ClearDelay = clearDelay;
    }
    #endregion

}

public class EqualCondition<T> : AlarmCondition
{
    #region Property declaration
    public T SetpointA { get; }
    #endregion

    #region Constructor
    public EqualCondition() { }

    public EqualCondition(TimeSpan activeDelay, TimeSpan clearDelay) : base(activeDelay, clearDelay)
    {
        SetpointA = setpointA;
    }
    #endregion

    public void EvaluateCondition(T value)
    {
        if(value.Equals(SetpointA))
        {
            Task.Delay(ActiveDelay).ContinueWith(_ => EvaluateConditionDelayed(value));
        }
    }

    private void EvaluateConditionDelayed(T value)
    {
        if (value.Equals(SetpointA))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Waited and worked");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Condition now false");
        }
    }
}

// In another file and namespace
public class ConsoleDisplay
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        EqualCondition<bool> condition1 = new EqualCondition<bool>(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5), new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5));
        EqualCondition<bool> condition2 = new EqualCondition<bool>(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2), new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5));

        condition1.EvaluateCondition(true);
        condition2.EvaluateCondition(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have what-ever-fancy-async-code but at the end you `.Wait()` for it to complete, you basically ruin all the asynchronicity.

Comment: When put in simple terms, it does make the whole thing seem useless. How could I get rid of the call to `.Wait()` whilst maintaining the whole waiting for `ActiveDelay` time before calling the next function ?

Comment: @MaxMichel you just remove the `Wait` call as i wrote in my answer(added code now).

Answer (score 1):

You can return `Task` from your method so the caller will decide if he wants to wait for the result. For example:

```
public async Task EvaluateCondition(T value)
{
    if(value.Equals(SetpointA))
    {
        await Task.Delay(ActiveDelay);
        EvaluateConditionDelayed(GetValue());
    }
}
```

Or just remove `.Wait()` (which blocks) from your current implementation if you don't want caller to have an option for such decision. The task should still print in the console even without it (if your program runs long enough):

```
public void EvaluateCondition(T value)
{
    if(value.Equals(SetpointA))
    {
        Task.Delay(ActiveDelay).ContinueWith(_ => EvaluateConditionDelayed(GetValue()));
    }
}
```

**UPD**

To start multiple `EvaluateCondition` and wait for them to finish in parallel you can use `Task.WhenAll`:

```
var ev1Task = EvaluateCondition(someVal1);
var ev2Task = EvaluateCondition(someVal2);
await Task.WhenAll(ev1Task, ev2Task);
```

If you don't want to await then just skip the `await Task.WhenAll(ev1Task, ev2Task)` (and fix the warnings).

Comment: Using this, I unfortunately get the same behaviour of a 5 second wait then a 2 second wait  but I would like the two to wait independently of each other

Comment: I've tried this but I can't use `await` in a main method hence this doesn't resolve the issue at hand unfortunately

Comment: @MaxMichel then just remove `Wait` from your code, as i wrote (code snippet before the UPD)

Comment: @MaxMichel also you can use blocking `Task.WaitAll` it does not need await.

Comment: As I said, I've done this. I no longer have a `.Wait()` in the call and it looks exactly like your second option. However, I still don't have the two calls performing their delay independently from each other (Also, the aim is to NOT block the program but rather wait in the background)

Comment: @MaxMichel then the issue is somewhere outside provided code cause I'm not able to [reproduce](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rKo6oa)

Comment: I will add an extensive code section to give you all I have

Comment: @MaxMichel: Maybe you can at a Thread.Sleep of at least 5 seconds in your `Main` method in the very end after calling `EvaluateCondition`. Then your program can wait until the sentences are printed to the console.

Comment: @SomeBody, Apologies for that, of course that was the problem (Which I couldn't see because I've been at this for hours on end). Thread.sleep pretends something is happening which is all I needed

Comment: @MaxMichel `Thead.Sleep` is not a good solution. It might work in this one specific case, but in any other case it may not, because it's waiting a specified time, not waiting for the job to complete. A better way is using `async`/`await` like this answer shows, but change your `Main()` method to be `public static async Task Main()`, which was made available in C# 7.1+, so that your app doesn't end before the work is complete.

Comment: @GabrielLuci I think `Thead.Sleep` is used just for demonstration/testing purposes as in my linked in comments reproducer.

Comment: @GuruStron I understand, but it's really not a good demonstration. It's better to demonstrate how to wait for a job to complete, rather than waiting a specified time that will hopefully be longer than it takes for the job to complete. Your answer does do that.